# Storybook.js. How to compile components as a ES5 lib

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, storybook

I'm using Storybook to develop & test my components in isolation. I use typescript, babel, etc. 
Everything works like a charm.
Now I want to compile my components as ES5 library (commonJS) and provide it to my other outer projects.

Basically storybook build command makes a whole storybook as a static website but I need the compiled components library.

The main problem here is that the storybook has some dependencies in node_modules that are ES6 modules, so babel configured to proceed them while Typescript handles my own components.
So I can't just use `tsc` etc. to compile my components eg `components` folder because typescript won't fetch and compile the dependencies from node_modules. They should be compiled to ES5, otherwise, any of my outer projects, that need to use compiled storybook components, won't be able to handle them.

Also, webpack has it's own aliases, so the whole tools zoo should be used during the deployment. 
How to do it in the case of Storybook?
Should I install the webpack, etc. manually into the storybook and configure a deploy process separated of the storybook? 
Can I just use the webpack of the storybook? (Because I've already configured it with Babel and Typescript).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way here - is using babel-cli and only transpile your components as a set of files

Example of the command:

```
npx babel src -d lib/ --copy-files
```

The link to the Babel CLI: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli
AFAIK, the configuration can include the typescript plugin